# How to validate username and password of user before log in in ASP.net Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

In my ASP.Net application, want to validate username and password of users before logging them into the application. I am using ASP.net Identity framework for membership.

Want to make sure whether the entered username and password exist or not.
something like this one `Membership.ValidateUser(username,password)` which was used in default membership but can not be used with ASP.net Identity. 
Tried this one but no luck?

```
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

var user = manager.Find(userName,Password);
```

Comment: Please mark aelagawy's answer as accepted as it seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 17):

```
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
var user = manager.FindByName(Email.Text);

//check for credentials before sign in ..    
var validCredentials = signinManager.UserManager.CheckPassword(user, Password.Text);
if (validCredentials)
{
    //sample code to run if user's credentials is valid and before login
    if(!manager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Administrators"))
    {
       FailureText.Text = "you need a higher permission level in order to login";
       return;
    }
}

//then sign in
var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);
```

Comment: don't forget the `await` if you are using the async versions (which you probably should be)

Answer (score 7):

I use something like this:

```
public static bool ValidateUser(string Email, string Password)
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindByName(Email);
        return SignInManager.UserManager.CheckPassword(user, Password); 
    }
```